# Results of 2 groups through eachother

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 2 groups, both will show the same 2 records (from the sql output) but grouped differently and shows different fields.
Output:

[image: a busy cat]

The 2nd result of group 1 is between the results of group 2. This is how Jaspersoft works.
But does someone have an idea how to keep the group results with eachother?

```
Group 1: result 1
Group 1: result 2
Group 2: result 1
Group 2: result 2
```

Any help or tips are appreciated.

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/509cP.jpg

**Jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.2.final using JasperReports Library version 4.7.0  -->
<!-- 2017-08-11T16:19:29 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a75576f0-e223-4e8a-8d52-67936178ea31">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="test"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="from_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="from_name2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="undgcode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="product_item_id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{product_item_id}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50" splitType="Prevent">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="40" y="10" width="220" height="30" uuid="ce52a200-b3dd-4b9b-bee4-30cc9db15aa5"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{from_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Group2" keepTogether="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{undgcode}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="64">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="140" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="28d2e565-98d6-4714-8420-81a3819ab46a"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Static Text]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="50" splitType="Prevent">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="40" y="10" width="220" height="30" uuid="857197bd-e4b6-404b-a527-19e63dd02a94">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{from_name2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Are you sure that in this case it should be two different groups? Maybe you can use one group (with combined values) and extract values from group value

Comment: Yes, the first group shows the items ordered by id, the second group shows the items grouped on UN code. So same query results but different need of output. 

Do you mean a crosstable for displaying/extracting values from a group?

Thanks.